# Question about RC charge-discharge curve

Tags: low-pass

I found the following image on [electronics-tutorials.ws](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/rc/rc_3.html):

[image]

Isn't this wrong? Shouldn't the voltage rise faster during the first 2T than that it decreases during the next half period? I think so because the voltage difference at t=0 is Vc, which is higher than the voltage difference at t=2T. Shouldn't the triangle wave ultimately go halfway Vc(max), with *difference* distributed evenly below and above the curve?
(I hope I make myself clear.)

Comment: I can't see the embedded picture - this may apply to other users of IE

Comment: @Andyaka I can see it in Firefox. Can you see it on the original page (link in question)?

Comment: @pebbles there are a bunch of pictures in the link and I don't know which one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it actually looks like this (doing a numerical integration of the differential equation):

[image: sawtooth ending up between about 0.12 and 0.88]

At equilibrium, the peaks of the sawtooth are at \${1\over 1+e^{T\over 2RC}}V_S\$ and \${e^{T\over 2RC}\over 1+e^{T\over 2RC}}V_S\$, where \$T\$ is the period of the square wave (different from the \$T\$ in the question plot).  For this example, that's about \$0.12V_S\$ to \$0.88V_S\$.

In that case equilibrium is reached very fast.  For a higher frequency square wave, it can take a few cycles.  In this example, the period of the square wave is \$RC\over 2\$ instead of \$4RC\$:

[image: slower rise for higher frequency]

Comment: Thanks. Just a nag: can't Mathematica do the DE analytically? :-)

Comment: Yes it certainly can, but that would take more care and feeding.  Doing it numerically with `NDSolve[]` was just one line.  Took about 30 seconds to type in, boom, done.  Then another line for the plot.  I did then solve analytically for the equilibrium peaks, though I didn't use `DSolve[]` since I already knew the equations.

Comment: Small request: could you make the vertical scale from 0 to 1 in the second graph too? It better shows the symmetry.

Answer (score 5):

Like Wouter says the discharge voltage should be negative to get this curve. More precisely it should be -*difference* V. So indeed, like you surmised the curve will end up halfway the charge and discharge voltages. Note that at t = 0 it will start from V = 0V, and over a few cycles move up.

Comment: Actually it gets to equilibrium very fast.  It's extremely close within one cycle.  The first peak is within 2% of the equlibrium peak, and the first trough is within 2% as well.  The next peak and trough are within 0.03%.

Comment: @MarkAdler: you're right that in this case equilibrium is reached fast, but I was thinking in more general terms. If the signal's period is much shorter than RC then it may take several cycles.

Comment: Yes, it will. I'll add an example of that to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You are right. The curve as shown requires that the discharge voltage is negative.